# How to logout from a Windows shared folder?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, network-shares

On my Windows XP, I am connected to a network shared folder on another Windows XP machine. I access the shared folder through UNC path, e.g.:
\Server\shared_folder1\
When I access it first time, it asks for login credentials; but second time onwards, it opens automatically without showing login dialog box (assuming the same credentials). But I need to use a different credential to access the same shared folder. How can I logout from the shared folder which I have already accessed in the current Windows session without restarting the system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can goto the command line and remove the shared drive:

```
net use /delete s:
```

Then you can reconnect as needed:

```
net use /persistent:yes s: \\server\dir
```

Comment: OP'd need `/user:domain\username` as well to switch credentials, otherwise this'd just default to his own user/pw

Comment: If not a mapped drive, the syntax is: `net use /delete \\server` Then wait about a minute for the connection to clear.

Answer (score 13):

Go to Control Panels/User Accounts

Change an account

Click your account

In "Related Tasks" click "Manage my network passwords"

Remove the network location you want to logout from

Comment: `net use \\servername /delete` usually works for me, but for some reason it didn't work last time I used it. This answer helped solve that problem. +1

Comment: Great answer. On my windows 7 PC, the location was slightly different: Start menu search "User Accounts", in your account, look left for "Manage Your Credentials". I was able to edit them right there, didn't even need to delete.

Answer (score 8):

Go to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager, it will have all the IDs and Passwords of the shared network folders that were saved.

[image]

Comment: EVERYONE: THIS IS THE BEST AND EASIEST ANSWER!! Use it, then vote it up to help others.

Answer (score 1):

1. Goto server dir `\\server\sharename`  or `\\server\`
2. Select `Tools -> Disconnect Network Drive...`
3. A window will popup. You select all highlighted and click "OK".
4. Now you can link to share folder with new user logon.

Comment: Judicious use of Markdown formatting can make this answer look much better. Edit your post, then click the `formatting help` link for more information.